# Prevent datalabel from appearing above or below pie chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to display a doughnut chart. The chart has dataLabels set up on it.

When the slice of the chart has a midpoint near the top or bottom of the chart, the dataLabel gets put above or below the chart image itself. When the chart renders, this causes the height of the chart to shrink, which is undesirable. What makes the shrinking even worse is the size of the doughnut "hole" is calculated from the height of the chart container and not the chart drawing, so it remains the same, which makes the chart itself very skinny.

Is there a way to prevent the labels from going above or below the chart and keep them from squishing the chart? Or a way I could add that functionality in via a certain event handler or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to modify [size](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size) parameter?

Comment: @SebastianBochan You, my friend, are perfectly correct! I was trying height and width options in the main chart settings. I didn't notice there was a separate "size" parameter in the plotOptions. Can you add this in as an answer so I can mark you correct?